# Header border doesn't cover entire top of page

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to html and css and when trying to make a navbar, the colour doesn't cover the entire top of page. I've tried adjusting the height and width but to no luck. [Here is what the webpage looks like at the moment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYl2G.png) As you can see, the blue header doesn't quite touch the top and sides. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <title>Noe ice-cream for you</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: gray;">
    
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="assets/subzero.png" alt="logo" class="logo" height="70px">

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>


            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>



</body>
</html>
```

And here is the style.css file:

```
h1{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.paragraph{
    font-size: medium;
    line-height: 62px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.container{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header{
    background-color:aqua;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.logo{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

nav{
    float: right;
}

header::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
  }

  nav li{
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 70px;
      padding-top: 50px;
  }

  nav a{
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #444;
  }

  nav a:hover{
      color:black;
  }
```

Comment: Add `body{ margin: 0;}` for no margin all side. Use `0, 10px, 20px, 30px` for top, right, bottom, left.

Answer (score 2):

You can add below on your style.css

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

or add

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reset-css@5.0.1/reset.css"
```

on your head tag before including tag link style.css

Comment: `padding: 0;` isn't necessary,  you only need `margin: 0;` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

try this in css :

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
 }
```

Comment: This `*` affect all elements. I think it is better to focus on `body` element. Just like `body {...}`.

Comment: yes * affect all elements

Comment: but padding and margin 0  for all element in starting

Comment: No problem, it's okay to use `*` if its result is what OP expect. In case that he want some element with default browser style then this will be the problem. :-)

Comment: @PRAKASHSOLANKI, the quality of this post would be greatly enhanced by incorporating the information in these comments into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Always start by resetting your document and setting the `box-sizing` property. With `box-sizing` padding and border are added to the element's height and width. So you can do something like this

```
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```